# Hang a swing from a Simpson deck tension tie

Tags: ceiling, hanging, swing

Theoretically, if the structure you attached this to https://www.strongtie.com/decks_decksandfences/dtt_tie/p/dtt could handle the weight. Could you suspend a swing from this thing? Put a strong enough eye bolt through the hole, and then hook a carabiner and swing to it?

Comment: They are probably not designed to hold something moving back and forth.  In time I would expect them to develop stress cracks and break apart.